# Getting oAuth Token using MSAL PublicClientApplication acquire_token_interactive method from Databricks is not working : InteractiveBrowserCredential

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-databricks

I am trying to get oAuth2.0 token to the protected resource using InteractiveBrowserCredential flow.
This is working from my local jupyter notebook however when i am trying to run it from Databricks notebook, it is unable to open browser (as Databricks cluster has no browser installed) and giving me below message

```
Found no browser in current environment. If this program is being run inside a container which has access to host network (i.e. started by `docker run --net=host -it ...`), you can use browser on host to visit the following link. Otherwise, this auth attempt would either timeout (current timeout setting is None) or be aborted by CTRL+C. Auth URI: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44093&scope={resource_id}%2Fuser_impersonation+offline_access+openid+profile&state=EvgdkFcNZTuJG&code_challenge=KR8zwfjhkuKYTGSlbaYAJNLVjXZHiE&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=33a1a12813342535455f398GHATf9c2cf21a8&client_info=1
```

I am trying to find out if there a way i can make it work, (by somehow using public redirect_uri to the Databricks cluster and driver node or in similar way). I can alternatively use device_code flow (it is working) however i want to see if i can by-pass one extra step of entering device code and directly authenticate using browser.

Please find the sample code i am using now below

```
import msal

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(self.CLIENT_ID, authority=self.AUTHORITY,token_cache= msal.TokenCache())
result = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=self.SCOPE)
```

Comment: If the device_code flow is working, I'd suggest you stick with that. Alternatively, you might consider using a Service Principal and dbutils.secrets to do the authentication and provide credentials. That way no user needs to log in.

Comment: @Will J : thanks for the suggestion.  i needed to authenticate using individual access privileges and i am trying to avoid the step of entering OTP again

Comment: @Despicableme did you ever find another solution to this? Either way it might be helpful for this question to have an answer with whatever solution or non-solution result you ended up. If you add that I'll gladly upvote your answer :)